# Angular loses binding in FormControl inside a virtual scroll

Tags: angular, forms, data-binding, scroll

I am using a Virtual Scroll component with a lot of input fields with an Form, but after I scrolled a bit my binding is broken. The values gets written to incorrect elements.

```
<form [formGroup]="animalForm" >
 
  <div *cdkVirtualFor="let animal of animalArray; >

    <input [id]="animal.Id"  cdkFocusInitial matInput type="text"  [formControlName]="animal.Id" />

  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</form>
```

Everything works correctly, but after the scrolling the ValueChange Listener get values for incorrect Ids (incorrect animals)

Comment: Your code is wrong. If you use formControlName, you should **remove** [value]

Comment: thanks for the hint, but the behaviours stays the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just to make a stackblitz and you're correct, the binding is wrong using formControlName :(.... but you can try use formControl :)

```
<input [id]="animal.Id"  cdkFocusInitial matInput type="text"  
    [formControl]="form.get(animal.Id)" />
```

See this [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v1ruyf?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html) -In the stackblitz I don't use matInput, it's the reason I'm not sure 100% that work-

Comment: thanks no Idea why they other approach loses the binding

Comment: see https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#view-recycling

Comment: cdkVirtualFor caches and reuses the same html elements. When a input[matInput] is reused, its formControlName value is updated but the component is already initialized and it doesn't receive the new form control value. The problem is not a wrong binding, it "simply" don't update the input element with the value of the new FormControl assigned. But it happens only when you assign a formControlName instead of a formControl.